# How to tell if Shift key is being held down

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I am making a first-person game using Babylon.js and I'm trying to add a feature where the player can sprint (`camera.speed` is increased) when holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, but <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> doesn't trigger the keydown event, so I was wondering if there is a way to add this trigger, either with Babylon or just with Javascript.

Comment: `shift` does not but `shift`+`w` does.

Comment: Right, but the issue with that is that it only checks if `shift` is being pressed when `w` is first pressed, so the player would be sprinting the entire time they held `w` down even if they let go of `shift`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. What I had to do was create an action manager attached to the scene, then add a trigger for when the shift key was pressed. Here's the final code:

```
const scene.actionManager = new BABYLON.ActionManager(scene);
scene.actionManager.registerAction(
    new BABYLON.ExecuteCodeAction({
        trigger: BABYLON.ActionManager.OnKeyDownTrigger,
        parameter: 16 // key code for shift
        }, () => {
            camera.speed = 0.8;
        },
        new BABYLON.PredicateCondition(scene.actionManager, () => {return camera.speed === 0.3}) // checks to see if it's already changed so it isn't setting the value every frame
    )
);
        
this.scene.actionManager.registerAction(
    new BABYLON.ExecuteCodeAction({
        trigger: BABYLON.ActionManager.OnKeyUpTrigger,
        parameter: 16
    }, () => {
        camera.speed = 0.3;
    })
);
```

This would also work for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, if you wanted to use it for crouch or some other function, you would just change `parameter: 17`.